# WP cron event firing, but doesn't hit breakpoint in debug

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem that I can't figure out. I've setup a custom WP cron schedule and a WP cron event with that schedule. I'm using PHPStorm to debug and I've set a breakpoint inside of the check_mail() hook. The break point never gets hit, yet the code inside of check_mail() gets executed since I can see the entry in my log file ("Got to check_mail()!")

All other breakpoints work fine and the check_mail() routine has only two lines of code in it - the log write and a return.

How does this happen that the code runs but my breakpoint is never hit?

In the constructor:

```
add_action( 'check_mail', array($this, 'check_mail' ), 10, 0);

if ( !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || !DOING_AJAX ) {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'schedule_wp_cron' ), 10, 0 );
}
```

The supporting routines:

```
public function schedule_wp_cron()
{
    /**
     * Avoid rescheduling cron if it's already scheduled.
     */

    $args = array( );

    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'check_mail' )) {

        /**
         * Schedule mail server polling.
         */
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'custom_interval', 'check_mail');

        }

    }

    public function check_mail( )
    {

        // **BREAKPOINT SET ON NEXT LINE**
        write_log( 'emails', 'Got to check_mail()!' );

        //... do something ...

        return;

    }


    public function custom_cron_schedule( $schedules )
    {

        $schedules[ 'custom_interval' ] = array(
            'interval' => 300,
            'display'  => 'Custom Interval',
        );

        return $schedules;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the breakpoint? I use PHPStorm a lot and love the debugging tool, but occassionally I find that the breakpoint placement doesn't work (for example, on certain parts of an array).  I also find that sometimes I simply have to quit / restart PHPStorm, because breakpoints stop firing / working for some reason.  NOTE that I do ALSO code WP, and the breakpoints - when working properly - DO stop execution when running via cron...

Comment: @cale_b I put it in check_mail() - I noted the line before. The line of code runs, but the breakpoint doesn't get hit. I haven't experienced this before. It's like the code is running in another process/instantiation of the class. Is there a way of debugging this possibility? Btw, I've exited PHPStorm and rebooted. I don't suspect PHPStorm at all.

Comment: Can you screenshot your Debug settings in PHPStorm and add them to the question?

Answer (score 9):

WP Cron tasks runs on separate process by remote POST request. PhpStrom will not stop on any breakpoint set in your code, because debug session start parameter is not present in request.

Here is solution. Filter will adds extra param to all WP Cron requests. Replace **XDEBUG_SESSION_START** value to yours (I've used default) and put code below to your plugin or theme code. PhpStorm will stop on any breakpoint even for cron tasks.

```
add_filter( 'cron_request', 'wp_cron_debug', 10, 2 );
function wp_cron_debug( $args, $doing_cron ) {

    $args['url'] = add_query_arg( array(
        'XDEBUG_SESSION_START' => 'PHPSTORM' // <== replace PHPSTORM with your key
    ), $args['url'] );

    return $args;

}
```

[PhpStrom IDE key value location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thqpA.png)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you very much!  I've been looking for a solution to this for several days.  See my answer below for a more general solution that doesn't require hard-coding the IDE Key.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Solved my problem. Crazy thing is that my php.ini file had no idekey configuration, and the port is 9003, but even though, I configured it to the you passed here, and 9001, and still it works! (I guess the port warks cause of the ports range, but no idekey? I guess thats the ID phpstorm pass to xdebug.

Answer (score 4):

[Pavel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146616/7751811) answer worked like a charm for me and I've been looking for an answer to this for several days.

But the more I thought about it, I wanted a more general solution...one in which I didn't have to hard-code a specific IDE Key.

This is what I came up with:

```
add_action ('cron_request', 'so_add_cron_xdebug_cookie', 10, 2) ;

/**
 * Allow debugging of wp_cron jobs
 *
 * @param array $cron_request_array
 * @param string $doing_wp_cron
 *
 * @return array $cron_request_array with the current XDEBUG_SESSION cookie added if set
 */
function
so_add_cron_xdebug_cookie ($cron_request_array, $doing_wp_cron)
{
    if (empty ($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'])) {
        return ($cron_request_array) ;
        }

    if (empty ($cron_request_array['args']['cookies'])) {
        $cron_request_array['args']['cookies'] = array () ;
        }
    $cron_request_array['args']['cookies']['XDEBUG_SESSION'] = $_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'] ;

    return ($cron_request_array) ;
}
```